# I don't know why the results of my code aren't the same?

Tags: python

**Here's the instructions:**

> This question deals with numbers that can be used as keys: two numbers
> are considered to be key if the largest of the two numbers is prime. A
> prime number is one that is divisible by 1 and itself. Your task is to
> write a python program that reads two integers (as described above)
> from the user and checks if they are valid keys. If the user inputs a
> float, the appropriate conversion must be done. If the user inputs a
> non digit number, the appropriate error catch must be used Allow the
> user to repeat the process as many times as she/he would like

Here is my attempt at an answer but the answers of this code keep changing and I don't know why...

```
i=1 

while i!=0: 
    int1=int(input("dear user please enter the 1st number ")) 
    int2=int(input("dear user please enter the 2nd number")) 
    largest=max(int1 , int2) 

    if largest >1: 
        for i in range (2, int(largest/2)+1): 
            if ( largest % i )== 0: 
                print("it cannot be a key ", largest) 
                break 
            else: 
                print("the key is ", largest) break print (" enter another keys")
```

Comment: What do you mean with "aren't the same"? Do you run your program two times, enter the same values and get different results?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that it prints "valid key" and "invalid key" in the same run, it's because it runs through every value for i, so for example `27 % 3 = 0` but `27 % 2 != 0` therefore it will for i = 3 print that it is a valid key.

To fix this you could do this:

```
valid_key = False
   
   if largest > 1:   for i in range(2, (int(largest/2)) + 1):
       if (largest % i) == 0:
         valid_key = False
         break
       else:
         valid_key = True
   
   if(valid_key):   
     print(largest, "is a valid key" 
   else:  
     print(largest, "is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for-else. It will check if the largest number can divide by i and if it doesn't divide by any of those numbers it will go for the else and say that its a prime number so it wont print negative and positive at the same time. Here's how to use it:

```
while 1 != 0:
    int1 = int(input("dear user please enter the 1st number "))
    int2 = int(input("dear user please enter the 2nd number"))
    largest = max(int1, int2)

    if largest > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(largest/2)+1):
            if (largest % i) == 0:
                print("it cannot be a key ", largest)
                break
        else:
            print("the key is ", largest)
        print("enter another keys")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, for every condition it is printing some or the other thing. You've to take a new variable which has some inital value. Check the if condition in loop, if the condition is satisfied, change the value of the variable. After completion, check if the variable value is changed or not. If changed, the condition was satisfied else, it was never satisfied. Your code:

```
i=1 
f=0
while i!=0: 
    int1=int(input("dear user please enter the 1st number ")) 
    int2=int(input("dear user please enter the 2nd number")) 
    largest=max(int1 , int2) 

    if largest >1: 
        for i in range (2, int(largest/2)+1): 
            if ( largest % i )== 0:
                f=1
                break 
    if f==1:
        print("It cannot be key")
    if f==0:
        print("It can be key")
    break
```